# css background header image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

my background image is not being displayed. I've used a link to the image but doesn't show. What could be the problem

```css
.header {
  background-image: url("https://www.africa.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Kenya.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.overlay{
 position: absolute;
 min-height: 100%;
 min-width: 100%;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 background: rgba(244, 244, 244, 0.79);
}
```

```html
 <header class="header">
   <div class="overlay"></div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `header` doesn't have a height... this should work.

```css
.header {
  background-image: url("https://www.africa.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Kenya.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 300px;
}

.overlay{
 position: absolute;
 min-height: 100%;
 min-width: 100%;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 background: rgba(244, 244, 244, 0.79);
}
```

```html
 <header class="header">
   <div class="overlay"></div>
</header>
```